# How should I position my minions when playing against a Mill Rogue's Vanish?

Tags: hearthstone

Against Mill Rogues, I tend to have a big hand and an even bigger board.

However, when the Mill Rogue casts Vanish, all my minions go back to my hand, and some of them, since my hand is too full, get discarded.

How should I position my minions so that the most valuable ones will be prioritized in returning to my hand?

Comment: Position doesn't matter, but order of play does. Note that minions with Deathrattle will have their Deathrattle triggered if you have a full hand when they are supposed to be returned to hand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The minions should be returned in the order in which they were put into play.

According to the [wiki](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Vanish), the position of the minions shouldn't matter, but the order you put them in should. The first minions that you put down go back first, so you can try to prioritize it that way.